# How can I create this type of graph in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6kI1.png)
I need to design this type of graph. The main thing is, how can I add these types of edges to connect the vertical nodes as well as the horizontal nodes? I tried the graphview SDK, but it didn't work for me. Can you guys suggest how we can design?